# Owin: host name (or ip) and port

Tags: asp.net, owin, katana

I have a classic owin startup class like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
    }
 }
```

Is there any way to get the host name (or ip) and port inside the 'Configuration' function ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you okay looking at specific requests (ie via `app.Run` or `app.Use`), or do you need it outside of that for something that's actually done as configuration? And if the former, are you looking for the *local* host name and port, or the remote one?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen yeah i need it outside any `.Run` or `.Use` :(
and i need it when it will be deployed

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I'm not sure. But I'm also not sure whether the host name makes a lot of sense. You could get the IP address from the NIC, perhaps, but that's assuming the server has only one. Beyond that, any DNS lookup would likely lead to something like "Server01," which isn't super useful.

Comment: an ip adress would be fine, i just updated the post.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
         //Get hostname
         string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

        // Get all ip address.
         IPAddress[] ips;
         ips = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);
    }
 }
```

To get all value from IAppBuilder you can do like this.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            foreach(var item in appBuilder.Properties)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " - " + item.Value);
                if(item.Key == "host.Addresses")
                {
                    dynamic d = item.Value;
                    var items = (Dictionary<string,object>)d[0];
                    // Here there are four keys for scheme , host , port , path
                    foreach(var add in items)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(add.Key + " - " + add.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thats an improvement, but how do i get the port ?

and its `System.Net.Dns` :)

Comment: You want port on which application is running ?

Comment: there is no 'host.Addresses' key in the `appBuilder.Properties` :(

Comment: If not then you can only get port when first request comes.